# What are the limits of the Feat Spell Perfection?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization

The reason I asked is because I think I found a bit of a loophole when using the feat that I'd like a bit of clarification on. Spell perfection states the following:

> Pick one spell which you have the ability to cast. Whenever you cast that spell you may apply any one metamagic feat you have to that spell without affecting its level or casting time, as long as the total modified level of the spell does not use a spell slot above 9th level. In addition, if you have other feats which allow you to apply a set numerical bonus to any aspect of this spell (such as Spell Focus, Spell Penetration, Weapon Focus [ray], and so on), double the bonus granted by that feat when applied to this spell.

This means specifically that you can apply *any* metamagic feat to the chosen spell, according to the rules-as-written. Which means that you could effectively Heighten, Persist, Quicken, Empower, or use any one metamagic feat to improve the casting of that one particular spell as long as they didn't go over ninth level.

This also means that You can Heighten a spell to 9th level without requiring a 9th level spell slot while simultaneously doubling the effect of spell focus, penetration, etc. I can think of a few spells where this would be incredibly useful, but I just want to clarify the limits to the feet as written before I start extrapolating and creating sorcerer builds based around this feat.

I also have one additional question that immediately ties into this extrapolation as well.

The Use magic device skill allows someone to Emulate a race at DC25 as far as activating magic items is concerned, assuming you had a wand of Paragon Surge, and was able to meet the DC25 UMD check to emulate a race(half-elf) does that mean that with the bonus feat that you get because of the casting of the spell that you could use it to gain access to Spell Perfection so that each individual day you could choose a spell to be able to flex metamagic with without raising the level of said spell as a non half-elf?

Comment: regarding [the use of a wand of Paragon Surge as a non-half-elf](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2oxng?Wand-of-Paragon-Surge-and-Use-Magic-Device)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **Yes**, you dont need to have 9th level spell slots to use spell perfection, thats why some 6-level casters take it. You simply make your own "perfect" version of said spell.

2) When a text says "you have the ability to cast" it means you must have it as a spell known or be able to memorize it, items that allow casting it will not meet the requeriments. I believe that recent FAQ's even ruled out spell-like abilities obtained from traits or racial abilities.

With that out of the way, **No**, because the wand has no requeriment to use it, the spell does, *only half-elves can cast paragon surge*, due to **Range: Personal (half-elf only)**. UMD would allow you to use a Paragon Surge wand without being one of the classes that can cast it:

> alchemist 3, bloodrager 3, cleric 3, magus 4, paladin 4, sorcerer/wizard 3, witch 3

The wand has no requeriment unless the creator choose to make it require a half-elf to use (which would lower the item cost), or enchanted the item (not a wand, but this happens to weapons, armors and wondrous items fairly often) with a special ability that requires a certain class or race.

A forgiving GM could even allow you to emulate a race to obtain a special ability from an item that only works for a certain race/class, like the [Belt of Dwarvenkind](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-of-dwarvenkind). Otherwise that specific use of UMD will not see much use.

3) If your character is an half-elf, you wouldnt need UMD at all and the answer would be: **Yes**, you can change the spell from spell perfection every day, on each cast of Paragon Surge, as long you also know three other metamagical feats.

Comment: So am I reading it correctly that a half-elf could make a wand of paragon surge and any other race would be able to use it? Because that's what it looks like I'm reading.

Comment: The spell requires you to be a half-elf, that cannot the changed unless you somehow find something that turns you into a half-elf.

Comment: Any race can use the wand, but the spell will fail because of the range: *Personal (half-elf only)*.